# How can I add vertical spacing between elements in a <div> on mobile view?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Currently, I have a `<div>` that is responsive.

Wide screen display:

[image]

Mobile display:

[image]

**How can I add vertical spacing between the 2 rows on the mobile display? I have tried adding a margin to each of the elements, however, I do not want the second row to have a `margin-bottom`.**

[image]

My code is as follows:

HTML

```
<div class="stats-flexwrap">
    <div class="stats">
        <span class="stats-row"><span>element 1</span>
        <span class="stats-row"><span>element 2</span>
        <span class="stats-row"><span>element 3</span>
        <span class="stats-row"><span>element 4</span>
     </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.stats-row {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 16px;
}

.stats {
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 788px) {
    .stats {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        max-width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        height: auto;
    }
    
    .stats-row {
        margin: 0 16px 0 16px !important;
        width: 120px;
    }
}

.stats-flexwrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way you can go about this using flex-box is to give a `margin-bottom` only to the first child of the flex-container.

```css
.stats-row {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 16px;
}

.stats {
  width: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 788px) {
  .stats {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .stats-row {
    width: 120px;
  }
  .stats *:nth-child(1) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}


.stats-flexwrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="stats-flexwrap">
  <div class="stats">
    <span class="stats-row">element 1</span>
    <span class="stats-row">element 2</span>
    <span class="stats-row">element 3</span>
    <span class="stats-row">element 4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This isn't the ideal way to go about this though. You may want to consider using CSS Grid instead to deal with vertical spacing.

This ensures that:

- vertical spacing is even between all elements using [gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap)
- layout remains responsive by filling up available space using grid [auto-fill or auto-fit](https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/)

You may look into more of these CSS Grid options by Googling around or viewing this [all-in-one guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) by CSS-Tricks. You can use this workaround for now if you wish to continue with flexbox (although this is discouraged).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gap` for spacing inside the grid:

```
gap: 25px;
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't too hard to add vertical margin. just use `nth-child()` selectors. 
You can whatever numbers you want to add, here I've use `margin: 0 10px 20px 10px;` on element 2 and `margin: 0 10px 0 10px;`on element 4. 
I haven't used `margin-bottom` on element 4, just on element 2.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .box:nth-child(2) {
    margin: 0 10px 20px 10px;
  }
  .box:nth-child(4) {
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">element 1</div>
  <div class="box">element 2 </div>
  <div class="box">element 3</div>
  <div class="box">element 4</div>
</div>
```

Let me know if it still doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to add line spacing is by using the `<br>` tag but to be more precise we could use line-height.

```
p.spacing {
    line-height: 2;
  }

<p class="spacing">
    This is first line
</p>
<p class="spacing">
    This is new line
</p>
```

Comment: The easiest way to add line spacing is by using <br> tag but to be more precise we could use line-height.

Answer (score 1):

By using the margin-bottom property also you can add margin bottom to your specific element.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="stats-flexwrap">
<div class="stats">
    <span class="stats-row"><span class="**ele_1**">element 1</span>
    <span class="stats-row"><span class="**ele_2**">element 2</span>
    <span class="stats-row"><span>element 3</span>
    <span class="stats-row"><span>element 4</span>``
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
**.ele_1{
   margin-bottom:8%;
      }
.ele_2{
   margin-bottom:8%;
      }**


.stats-row {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 16px;
           }

.stats {
width: auto;
display: flex;
       }

@media screen and (max-width: 788px) {

.stats {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
}

.stats-row {
    margin: 0 16px 0 16px !important;
    width: 120px;
    }
  }

.stats-flexwrap {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-around;
  }
```